# How to change all references to a single array to null in Java

Tags: java, arrays, reference

I have multiple methods, each of which holds a reference to a single array. In one method where I have such a reference, I want to change the array to `null`. The problem is, I don't just want to change one reference to `null`, but all of them. Does Java have a way of doing this?

```
public void moo()
{
    boolean[] cow = new boolean[10];
    baa(cow);

    assertEquals(true, cow == null);
}

private void baa(boolean[] sheep)
{
    *do stuff*
}
```

In other words, what can I do in `baa()` to sheep so that `arr` is `null` and the assert in `moo` is true?

Thank you!

Comment: oops... that was what `cow` used to be called, before I changed it to *try* to be less confusing... oops!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no you cannot.  `cow` is a reference to the actual array and you are passing a copy of `cow` to the method `baa`.  There is no way to change the original reference without using some kind of trickery.

However, one trick you can use is to write your own wrapper class.  This way you can pass around a reference to a reference to `cow`.

```
public class CowWrapper {
    public boolean[]cow;
    public CowWrapper(boolean[]cow){
        this.cow=cow;
    }
}
public void moo() {
    CowWrapper cow=new CowWrapper(new boolean[10]);
    baa(cow);
    assertNull(cow.cow);
}
public void baa(CowWrapper sheep) {
    sheep.cow=null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, nothing.

You can't actually change the arguments to methods.  They're copies.

Your assertEquals as written will always fail.

Answer (score 0):

If `arr` is a field in the class, `arr = null;` should do fine. You can't do anything to `sheep` in `baa` to make `arr` null.

If `arr` is not a field in the class, where did it come from in your code?

Comment: edited to fix my mistake leaving `arr` in there. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the array in `baa()` and have `baa()` return an `boolean[]` instead of `void()`:

```
public void moo()
{
    boolean[] cow = new boolean[10];
    cow = baa(cow);
    System.out.println((cow == null) ? "True" : "False");
}

private boolean[] baa(boolean[] sheep)
{
    sheep = null;
    return sheep;
}
```